# OpenCart show own module on sidebar

Tags: php, module, opencart, frontend

I'm working in OpenCart 1.5.5 on some sort of newsmodule for in the side bar. I've got it all running in the back-end, but i don't know how i could asign this module `module/aselsi` to the right side bar on the home page, product page and category page.

I've already looked in some source code's, but i don't fully understand how this particilur thing works. 
I did try to make it work by inserting in the DB tabels `oc_layout and oc_layout_route` some info, but that also didn't work.

So my question is: How can i make my extension / module apear on the front-page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By `running in the back-end` I guess You have created a custom controller, model and view for some form where You manage Your news. That is OK.

But since this should be a module You also have to create a *backend* part for this module so that it could be installed and assigned to the layout on certain pages. The simplest way how to do this is to copy these files:

- `admin/controller/module/banner.php`
- `admin/language/<YOUR_LANGUAGE>/module/banner.php`
- `admin/view/template/module/banner.php`

into Your new

- `admin/controller/module/aselsi.php`
- `admin/language/<YOUR_LANGUAGE>/module/aselsi.php`
- `admin/view/template/module/aselsi.php`

and rename all the class names, constants, model and language file names from `banner` to `aselsi`. After this You should see a new **Aselsi** module under Extensions > Modules in You administration where You should be able to assign this module to pages and positions...

Just want to mention that simple copy-paste + rename is not enough, You would have to edit some other parts as well to get it working.

**EDIT:** I'm not at the code right now, but yes, You are right, it has a lot to do with that line You are mentioning in comment. Each module setting is saved as serialized string (which is a serialized array) which contains module settings - layout, position, sort_order, etc. The key is the *module key* - `aselsi` in Your case, same as all other modules has their own modules. By only installing the module You set the module *as active* but You can show the module by saving it's settings. In frontend *controllers* for left, right column and top and bottom content the *active* modules are then populated and all set to display on that layout and on that position are displayed then.

The installing/uninstalling of module (in backend) can be extended to e.g. add/remove new DB tables for that module and/or for altering current DB tables (by adding new columns, etc.) by implementing `install` and `uninstall` methods with their respective logic.

I hope this simple explanation helps a little.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answer. I've indeed got an custom controller blahblah. AND i already got it in the module map, so i already did install it. But i will take a look at the banner code then and copy and paste ( and edit ) and i will see how far i will come. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, it works. I understand it got something to do with this line: `$this -> model_setting_setting -> editSetting('aselsi', $this -> request -> post);` but i don't realy understand how that would make it work... But i will figure out later, now i'm to glad that it works :D

Comment: You are welcome. I added a simple explanation on how this works.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. It's getting much clearer now :D